# Flash FLVPlayBack Video goes FULLSCREEN instead of the Application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a Flash App and its a presentation. I want the App to go full screen but there is an FLVPlayBack component playing a video now instead of the App the `StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN` turns the video to full screen.

When I remove the video it works fine but I need that video there.

Any idea what is going wrong here ?

_Iza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the `fullScreenTakeOver` parameter of your `FLVPlayback` Component to `false` before the FULL_`SCREEN` Code. Hope that will resolve that Video takeover issue.

```
var yourFLVPlaybackComp:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
    yourFLVPlaybackComp.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
```

Comment: Looks promising let me try it

Comment: This, saved me a day, I was almost ready to code my app in another language.